# Is there any way to completely disable the physical power button on a laptop (running Windows 10)?

Tags: laptop, windows-10, power

Is there any way to completely disable the physical power button on a Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro laptop running Windows 10? When I say disable, I mean completely (so not allowing reset even if you hold it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a combination hardware/software switch for the majority of systems. You can disable the quick press action in software no problem, but typically the long press (to force power off) is tied into a watchdog system that cannot be overridden in pure software. Power it on and put a glob of hot-melt glue over it? Or some sort of bar over the button if possible, I'm sure someone could fabricate a restrictive case for you easily.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the laptop.  On many / most laptops you could open them up and physically remove the button or wedge it so that it can't be pressed (I've done this with an old Dell laptop.

This typically can't be done in software - and, of-course, unless you take steps to prevent it there is nothing stopping someone pulling out the power and battery.

Comment: I agree. When I take apart laptops I truly don't pay attention to how the power button is hooked up to the board. It may be as simple as removing a connector from the motherboard, but a software implementation of this, more than likely does not exist.

Comment: But in the windows 10 settings I found an option for the power button (whether to make it sleep or do nothing). This means the button isn't some sort of switch (and can be a registered event through software). Unfortunately I couldn't find an option for how long the button is pressed. Maybe in device manager or something?